# justify-content: flex-start is not working

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, flexbox

I was trying to align all the elements in the website to have at most 3 elements in a row and have them align to the left.

But I got the following result. [(website image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTtKz.png)

I used Ruby on Rails to create this website so it might be hard to realize the code for some people.

My code

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
}

.blog {
  border: 4px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2% auto;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 33%;
  max-width: 33%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.blog-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.new-blog-form {
  margin: 0px 30%;
}

.text-area {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}

.title-input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>My Blog</title>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <h1>My Blogs</h1>
  <div class="blog-container">
    <% @blogs.each do |blog| %>
      <div class="blog">
        <p class="title">
          <%= blog.title %>
        </p>
        <p class="time">
          <%= blog.created_at %>
        </p>
        <%= link_to 'Learn More', blog_path(blog), class: "btn btn-info" %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <%= link_to 'New Blog', '/blogs/new', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Any suggestion is helpful to me. Thank you.

---

Update:

The problem was solved by erasing two margin statements, one in .blog and one in .blog-container

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try removing `margin: 2% auto` on `.blog`

Comment: if you have `justify-content: flex-start`  on the class `.blog-container` why did you add `margin: 0 auto;` these two work against each other!!

Comment: @Adam I was trying to put the container at the center of the page in order to have a organized page outlook.

Comment: but you can't have both! that won't help figure out the problem

Comment: Here check this might be helpful [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: @Adam Yeah I understood now. I like this website, thank you for sharing that. I guess I will just use another flex for this whole block to make it center.

Comment: add `justify-content: center` to the parent and add `margin: 5px` for the child then they be centered with space between. Check this [pen](https://codepen.io/adamragheb/pen/RydRpG)

Comment: @Adam This is another cool feature of flex, but what I want to do is to keep the blog-container at the center of the screen instead of putting the whole thing to the left. I've done it by containing blog-container into a div and let this div display flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem was solved by erasing two margin statements, one in .blog
>   and one in .blog-container

I don't know if you can post an answer to your own question.  If not, I'm posting your answer here so you can mark this question as answered.  Thanks.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I'm just a StackOverflow beginner.  If there is a better way to mark a question as answered, let me know @JasonMcFarlane.  I use the Unanswered list to find questions to answer and it's disappointing to read through everything just to find out the user already has an answer.